# Finding the norm of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, linear-transformations, normed-spaces

If the matrix

\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 3\\
0 & 3
\end{pmatrix}

represents a linear transformation on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and we consider the norm $||\cdot||_2 = (a^2 + b^2)^{1/2}$ for the vector $<a,b>$ as the usual Euclidean norm (distance formula between two points), how do we find the norm of this matrix? Is it just the maximum of the norms of each column of the matrix?

I am confused about the right way to proceed because I have also read that we can take the matrix times its transpose and use the maximum eigenvalue of that symmetric matrix as the norm of the original one. But that doesn't require the norm at all though and in this question I have to use the norm.

Comment: The simplest way is to follow the procedure $\|A\|=\sqrt{\|A^TA\|},$ where the norm of $A^TA$ is equal to the largest eigenvalue of that matrix. In your particular case you should pull out the factor $3$ before you start the procedure, to simplify calculations. Another approach could be: maximize $(x+y)^2+y^2$ for $x^2+y^2=1,$ take a square root of the outcome and multiply the result by $3.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc but this does not use the specific norm that the question asks for though and that's where my confusion is.

Comment: The second suggestion of maximizing subject to the unit norm requirement for the vector uses the specific Euclidean norm

Comment: @Paul What do you mean by "specific Euclidean norm" ? The matrix is given and I take for granted that the basis vectors are orthogonal. Otherwise the first method does not make sense as the transpose depends on the inner product. It is not the mechanical transpose of the table with coordinates.

Comment: The first method does require the norm. For  a linear transformation in Euclidean real space the transpose transformation is defined by $\langle A^Tv,w\rangle =\langle v, Aw\rangle .$ If the linear transformation $A$ is represented as the matrix with respect to orthonormal basis then $A^T$ is represented by the transpose of the matrix $A.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc But nowhere does this use the formula for the Euclidean norm. To get eigenvalues of the matrix $A*A^{T}$ you find the solution of the equation $det(A-\lambda I) = 0$ and then take the square root of the max one as the norm. But this question wants us to use $||\cdot||_2$

Comment: You have to calculate the eigenvalues of $AA^T,$ not of $A.$ For example if $$A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 &1\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix}$$ the norm is equal $1$ although both eigenvalues are equal $0.$

Comment: Indeed. My mistake. But my question is still the same though. Nothing in that eigenvalue method requires $||\cdot||_2$ even though the question does...

Comment: There is a general theorem. If a matrix $B$ is symmetric, then its norm is equal to the maximal absolute value of all eigenvalues of $B.$ The proof makes use of $\|\cdot \|_2$ norm. In the case $B$ is of the form $B=A^TA$, the matrix $B$ is symmetric and its eigenvalues are nonnegative.

Comment: $||A \underline{v}|_2^2=(3x+3y)^2+(3y)^2$, which you want to maximise subject to $\underline{v}=<x, y>$ being a unit vector. This is a straightforward Lagrange multiplier problem.